# Defined names not recognized in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, defined

I have done a test run on using defined names from excel and then using them in VBA to fill ActiveX ComboBoxs as shown below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim dogs1 As Object

Dim Sh As Worksheet
'Me.all.Clear

If Choose = "dogs" Then
    With Sheets("dogs")
        all.ListFillRange = "dogs1"
        Debug.Print all
    End With
ElseIf Choose = "Cats" Then
    With Sheets("cats")
        all.ListFillRange = "Cats"
        Debug.Print all
    End With
End If



End Sub

Private Sub Choose_Click()

With Sheets("Index")
Choose.ListFillRange = "animalL"
End With

Worksheets("Print").Select
Worksheets("Interface").Select

End Sub
```

This one works like a dream, using my defined names from excel. however I am now trying to implement this in my actual program and the defined names are not working. I did have a similar problem when building the animal drop downs but that was only because I didn't make them workbook (global) names, but I am doing this and now I am at a loss of what is wrong. Here is the code I am working on:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim Sh As Worksheet

Me.MFG.Clear
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Me.MFG.AddItem Sh.Name
Next Sh

If MFG.Value = "Kawneer" Then
    With Sheets("Kawneer")
        Disc.ListFillRange = "Frames"
        Debug.Print Frame
    End With
ElseIf MFG.Value = "PRL" Then
    With Sheets("PRL")
        Disc.ListFillRange = "test"
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

my option explicit is saying my Frames defined name is not defined, but it should be which means test isn't reading in either, so it's not a specific problem, but an overall problem with my defined names. All are set to workbook(I tried doing them as separate worksheets too), and when I test it in excel they work just fine (example click on cell press "=" and then type in Frames, it gives me my range). I didn't add my ComboBox code because it seems to be working fine, just can't get the defined names to work. Thanks

Comment: `Debug.Print Frame` you don't have any variable declared named `Frame` and so with `Option Explicit` you get a compile error

Comment: @TimWilliams, I did try Dim as Variant and other dims as well, but it returned nothing when I tried this and also my other program runs without needing to define it. If it's already a defined name does it need to be redefined in VBA?

Comment: `Debug.Print Frame` is trying to print the value of a variable named "Frame" - *you have no variable with this name*.  Note that local variable names and names of defined names are two entirely different things.  Also your range name is "Frames" which is not the same as "Frame"

Comment: @TimWilliams that make sense, but how do I "pull in" a defined name? and even more confusing still, why is my other program running fine?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pull in".  If you comment out the Debug.Print then what error do you get, and on which line?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't get any error, but I just don't get anything period. When I ran my other program, when I got it to print is when it started working.

Comment: Have you put breakpoints on the lines where the listfill is set, to make sure they're actually executing?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have not I'll give it some more time trouble shooting and let you know. Thanks